# How to set the webview fit to the window in java?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, layout-manager

How to set the webview fit to the window?

If I resize or maximize the screen the webview not fit to the window .

My Code :

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * SwingFXWebView
 */
public class SwingFXWebView extends JPanel {

    private Stage stage;
    private WebView browser;
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private JButton swingButton;
    private WebEngine webEngine;

    public SwingFXWebView(){
    super(new BorderLayout());
    initComponents();
    }

   public static void main(String ...args){
    // Run this later:
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            frame.getContentPane().add(new SwingFXWebView());

            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }

 private void initComponents(){

    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    createScene();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    swingButton = new JButton();
    swingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webEngine.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    swingButton.setText("Reload");

    add(swingButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

  /**
  * createScene
  *
  * Note: Key is that Scene needs to be created and run on "FX user thread"
  *       NOT on the AWT-EventQueue Thread
  *
   */
  private void createScene() {
    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            stage = new Stage();

            stage.setTitle("Hello Java FX");
            stage.setResizable(true);

            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,80,20);
            stage.setScene(scene);

            // Set up the embedded browser:
            browser = new WebView();
            webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("https://www.google.com/");

            ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
            children.add(browser);

            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }
    });
}
}
```

If I maximize the webview it comes like this

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxFpE.png)

If I resize or maximize the screen the webview not fit to the window .

I want to set the webview fit to the screen if I resize or maximize the window.

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possibly `public SwingFXWebView(){ ..` should be `public SwingFXWebView(){ super(new BorderLayout()); ..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you give more details ?

Comment: .. can you try it and report the result back? If you the problem is still not solved, can you be more specific about what 'details' you need? That would be a good time for more words, not less.

Comment: i can't understand your suggestion. Can I apply like this ?   `public SwingFXWebView(){
    initComponents();
 super(new BorderLayout()); 
    }` can you give detail explanation?

Comment: Add `super(new BorderLayout());` immediately after `public SwingFXWebView(){`. Remove nothing. By default, a `JPanel` has a `FlowLayout`, which shows components at their preferred size no matter how big the panel is. But a `BorderLayout` has different behavior. Any component added to one without a constraint defaults to the `CENTER`. A component in the center of a border layout will be stretched to the width and height of the available space.

Comment: @AndrewThompson   I edited my code in question. According to your suggestion I edited my code but , it didn't worked.